# RuntimeException: crypto.Merlin cannot create instance

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, ws-security, weblogic11g, rampart

I have installed weblogic 11g on linux ubuntu server. I have deployed my web services on weblogic. When I am trying to access my webservice from SOAP UI(installed at my local window machine), I am getting below mentioned exception.

```
    org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin cannot create instance
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin cannot create instance
        at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.CryptoFactory.loadClass(CryptoFactory.java:231)
        at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.CryptoFactory.getInstance(CryptoFactory.java:95)
        at org.apache.rampart.util.RampartUtil.getSignatureCrypto(RampartUtil.java:398)
        at org.apache.rampart.RampartEngine.process(RampartEngine.java:136)
        at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartReceiver.invoke(RampartReceiver.java:92)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:318)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:254)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:160)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:173)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:144)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at com.csdcsystems.amanda.servlet.AmandaAxisServlet.service(AmandaAxisServlet.java:91)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:184)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3729)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin cannot be cast to org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Crypto
        at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.CryptoFactory.loadClass(CryptoFactory.java:217)
```

I have my jks file in my class path. After some googling I have found that Rampart is looking at the wrong cacerts file as per below URL:

http://emelnikov.blogspot.in/2013/04/org.html

I have added property in my services.xml, but still I am getting the same error. I added below property:

```
<ramp:property name="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.load.cacerts">false</ramp:property>
```

Please note that when web services are deployed at weblogic installed at windows environment, everything is working fine.

Please help me identifying what I am missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you added this property to WSDL and re-generate it?

Comment: hi herry, please add more details. I am not understanding what you are trying to say here. I am not creating wsdl and then java classes. I have added this property in services.xml which is defining the policy for security.

Comment: I think the Rampart use Axis. So it is Axis property, am I wrong? So if it is, I think is better regenerate these WSDL's which generated with Axis.

Comment: Axis2 uses Rampart to provide security in web services. Above mentioned property is part of Rampart. Anyways, WSDL automatically gets regenerated if any change is made in configuration when ever we are calling service url with "?wsdl" appended with it.